# Can't make a reference to google-play-service lib. How can i fix it?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am beginner in android app development, and i am now learning how to build a app by using Google map API v2.

Something like this: 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/

However, i can't make a reference to google-play-service lib in Eclipse

The following is my steps:

1. Right Click-> Properties-> Andriod-> Library-> Add the google play service lib from my workspace
2. It seem work (have a green tick) before I press the OK button
3. But when i do the redo the step 1 to check  it , the green tick become a red cross

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the eclipse and do it again and if still does not work check that the library you are linking is in the same partition of your hard drive as the project. They have to be in same drive to work properly with eclipse

Answer (score 0):

go to your project properties, then build path, then order and export. make sure it is ticked..

if that dosnt make an empty object of any class in play services and hover it, then go to fix project setup.... in there should be either add jar or add library....